# capistrano not log the info output for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, capistrano3

I tried to run `bundle exec cap production deploy`
it was nothing happen, no-log no error, and no info what's going on, why ???
and I check on log
it only said:

```
  INFO START 2020-05-23 15:58:36 +0800 cap production deploy
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Capfile` :

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require 'capistrano/rails'

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "capistrano/rbenv"
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Nginx

require "whenever/capistrano"

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

`config/deploy.rb`:
i cant put a lot of code here because the rule of SO:
so i put the file on [here](https://slexy.org/view/s2CS4xGA4G)

i dont edit any on config/deploy/production.rb

Comment: Could you post more information? Your `Capfile`, `config/deploy.rb`, and `config/deploy/production.rb` would be good to start.

Comment: just edit it , sorry be able to respond, were find out it but still cant fix it , i updated my question for your request, @will_in_wi